# Mongoose 3.4.0 returns [object Object] instead of actual values - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my schema

```
var elementSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  storage: {
    url: String,
    type: String
  }
});
```

However when I:

```
var newElement = new Element();
  newElement.storage = {};
  newElement.storage.url = "asd";
  newElement.storage.type = "asd";
  console.log(newElement.storage);
```

I get `[object Object]`, whilst it should return `{url:"asd",type:"asd"}`

In facts, if I go and query it, I get:

```
{
  storage: "[object Object]",
  bubble: ObjectId("510880b82e6e350200000002"),
  _id: ObjectId("5113c0c0786ece0000000001"),
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use a field named `type` in an embedded sub-document like `storage`, you have to use an explicit definition or Mongoose gets confused:

```
var elementSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  storage: {
    url: String,
    type: { type: String }
  }
});
```

Comment: This get's me all the time and I can never remember the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

don't use `console.log()`, use instead

```
var util = require('util');
util.inspect(newElement.storage);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this doesnt solve the problem though. :(