# Why mongoose gives me [object Object]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema defined as:

```
var Theme = mongoose.model( 'Theme', {
id: String,
name: String,
background: {
    url: String,
    color: String
},
text: {
    color: String,
    highlight: String
},
paper: {
    background_color: String,
    opacity: Number,
    font: {
        family: String,
        size: Number,
        color: String
    },
    font_shadow: {
        x: Number,
        y: Number,
        blur: Number,
        color: String,
        opacity: Number
    },
    border: {
        size: Number,
        type: String,
        color: String,
        opacity: Number
    },
    shadow: {
        x: Number,
        y: Number,
        blur: Number,
        spread: Number,
        color: String,
        opacity: Number
    }
} 
});
```

Schema is defined in appropriate node.js file.
And I have corresponding document in my DB:

```
_id: ObjectId("5397557574c5e235160008c5"),
id: "scifi-1",
name: "Sci-fi light",
background: {
   url: "/bgr/1.jpg",
   color: "#223388"
},
text: {
   color: "#333333",
   highlight: "#555555"
},
paper: {
   background_color: "#444444",
   opacity: 0.8,
   font: {
     family: "anonymous",
     size: 14,
     color: "#888888"
   },
   font_shadow: {
     x: 0,
     y: 0,
     blur: 5,
     color: "#123456",
     opacity: 0.5
   },
   border: {
     size: 1,
     type: "solid",
     color: "#666666",
     opacity: 0.8
   },
   shadow: {
     x: 0,
     y: 0,
     blur: 5,
     spread: 0,
     color: "#ff0000",
     opacity: 0.5
   }
}
```

The problem here is that upon successfully retrieving a database document via ajax call, everything is fine, except that the "border" have [object Object] kind of data, which, as you can see is not what it should be.

Here's an [output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qmSVnSmY), just in case.

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The reason seems to that you cannot use "type" as variable name. Either I have to use different name, or I can define it such way:

```
...
type: {type: String}
...
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755185/820948
Will mark it as solved in 2 days due to restrictions.

Comment: Or you could realize you just identified your own question as a duplicate. But now you posted a self answer so I guess it is up to others to sort that out.