# MongoDB - How to define multiple datatypes for a field in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "title": "This an item",
    "date":1000123123,
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "html",
            "content": "<h1>Hi there, this is a H1</h1>"
        },
        {

            "type":"img",
            "content": [
                {
                    "title": "Image 1",
                    "url": "www.google.com/1.jpg",
                    "description":"This is the first image"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "map",
            "content": [
                {
                    "lat":323434555,
                    "lng":4444343434,
                    "description":"this is just a place"
                }
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the "data" fiel stores an array of objects where the "content" field is variable.

How should I model that in Mongoose?

This is how I defined my schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('TestObject', new Schema({
    title: String,
    date: Date,
    data: [
        {
            type: String,
            content: Object
        }
    ]
}));
```

And this is the response for the "data" field:

```
"data": [
    {
        "type":"img",
        "content": [ "[object Object]" ]
    },
    {
        "type":"map",
        "content": [ "[object Object]" ]
    }
]
```

What is the correct way to define a varying datatype for an object in Mongoose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) type could meet your requirement

> An "anything goes" SchemaType, its flexibility comes at a trade-off of it being harder to maintain. Mixed is available either through `Schema.Types.Mixed` or by passing an empty object literal.

```
data: [
    {
        type: String,
        content: Mixed
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks zangw, it returns "content": [ "[object Object]" ] as well. In case that is OK, do you know how can that be parse to get the data? I use JSON.parse, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Boel, try `toObject()` method, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: the problem was with the definition of the "type" field, as pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755185