# How declare Mongoose field which can be boolean or string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save boolean or string type in field, how can I do this?

```
 {
   enum: [{
     type: Boolean || String
   }]
 }
```

not working :(

How can I do this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - How to define multiple datatypes for a field in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458392/mongodb-how-to-define-multiple-datatypes-for-a-field-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should not do this. Types are there for reasons like - consistency, validation, optimization, you name it.

If your field can be two different types - probably that is two different fields.

```
type: [Boolean | String]

can probably be split as 

isSomethin: [Boolean],
type: [String]
```

If you really want to do it you can use Mixed https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed or Custom schema types https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html