# Boolean and Number in Schema (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, mongoose

How to make in one of the values in the schema, 2 data types Boolean and Number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - How to define multiple datatypes for a field in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458392/mongodb-how-to-define-multiple-datatypes-for-a-field-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is if there is a way to have a single field that can be of type Number or Boolean. If that is the case, you can accomplish this with a Custom SchemaType (See mongoose docs on this topic at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html). The code would be something like this:

```js
class BoolOrNumber extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  constructor(key, options) {
    super(key, options, 'BoolOrNumber');
  }

  // `cast()` takes a parameter that can be anything. You need to
  // validate the provided `val` and throw a `CastError` if you
  // can't convert it.
  cast(val) {
    let _val = Number(val);
    if (isNaN(_val) && val !== true && val !== false) {
      throw new Error('BoolOrNumber: ' + val + ' must be a number or boolean');
    }
    return _val;
  }
}

// Don't forget to add `BoolOrNumber` to the type registry
mongoose.Schema.Types.BoolOrNumber = BoolOrNumber;
```