# defining 2 types under 1 variable in mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Schema that looks like this:

```
const exampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    topic: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
    },
    words: {
         type: String || Array: {
              type: String,
              required: true,
             }
         required: true,
     }
});
```

I've read about custom types in mongodb but don't understand what the documentation is showing me. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boolean and Number in Schema (Mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886401/boolean-and-number-in-schema-mongoose)

Comment: sadly yes but it's too complicated for me. I don't understand how to create it nor how it works. I edited my question in the hopes someone could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating [custom schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html#creating-a-basic-custom-schema-type) in mongoose,

```
class StringOrArray extends mongoose.SchemaType {
    constructor(key, options) {
        super(key, options, 'StringOrArray');
    }

    cast(val) {
        // please change your logic as per your requirement
        if (typeof val !== 'string' && !Array.isArray(val)) {
            throw new Error('StringOrArray: ' + val + ' must be a String or Array');
        }
        return val;
    }
}

// Don't forget to add `Int8` to the type registry
mongoose.Schema.Types.StringOrArray = StringOrArray;
```

Use `StringOrArray` in your schema,

```
const exampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    topic: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    words: {
        type: StringOrArray,
        required: true
    }
});
```